# Dart2JS Cannot get async code to run when converted from Dart to Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, dart, dart2js, dart-2

```
main() async {
  print('Hello World');
  await getAsyncString().then((hello) => print(hello));
}

Future<String> getAsyncString() async {
  return 'Hello Async World';
}
```

This is my code example, `index.dart`. It is in my web folder.

I run `webdev build` to compile to js.

When I run `dart web/index.dart` in my web folder
I get the expected output of

```
Hello World
Hello Async World
```

When I run `node build/index.dart.js` or `index.js` I only get

```
Hello World
```

Is the async code running and is this expected behavior?

The full output is too long to post.

Steps to reproduce:

`touch testcompile.dart`

add the code

`dart2js -O2 -o index.js testcompile.dart`

`node index.js`

Comment: If you can provide the generated Javascript code from your `index.dart.js`, it may be helpful to people attempting to answer the question.

Comment: The output is too long to place in the question. 

It is relatively easy to replicate though. For anyone interested, install the dart sdk https://www.dartlang.org/tools/sdk

`touch testcompile.dart`,
add the code,
`dart2js -O2 -o index.js testcompile.dart`,
finally `node index.js`